# Running JPA project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jpa

I have a problem running JPA project withing Eclipse IDE. Creating project works, I put it in a Tomcat runtime, but yet it doesn't show in Tomcat (normal web apps do).
I have installed Web Tools Platform SDK from eclipse repos and Tomcat 7 server, connected to Eclipse. Any ideas how to fix that?
Thanks in advice,
Dracco

Comment: When you clean or build your project, does Eclipse show any errors?

Comment: Are you using Maven? If not I presume all related jar files are in WEB-INF/lib folder. Besides have you added your project to server by right clicking Server and adding project using Add/Remove in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm not using Maven, that was a Project -> JPA Project.
The point in adding it to server is that it does not show in Resources list :(.

Comment: Which package and version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Juno, Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Answer (score 2):

Add **Server Runtime** in your Preferences.

Choose the appropriate version of Tomcat from there and mention the path to the Tomcat directory.

Comment: I do have Tomcat7 in Server -> Runtime Environment, normal projects do read it, JPA not.